# Investor estimates a fortune "t" years from now, show initial growth rate

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, exponential-function

an investor estimates his fortune in "t" years' time will be: (in thousands of dollars)

$ y(t) = 12[(t/10) + 1]^{3/2}$

a) what is the initial growth rate of his fortune? (give as percent per year)

$ y'/y $  (at t=0)

b) determine the time when the growth rate is equal to $0.1$ (10% per year)

I cannot for the life of me differentiate this and get to a proper conclusion.  for part a, i keep getting values that do not make sense. I know the initial growth rate should logically be be > 10%, as part b asks you when it will go down to 10%.

please show a step by step solution, I would like to use this question as a reference to plug in other values to study from.

Comment: What did you get for $y'$?  You are correct that you want to solve $\frac {y'(t)}{y(t)}=0.1$

Comment: I don't know how to properly tackle this problem to get y'.  I took the natural log of both sides and got $ y' = (y)(190 - 12t)/(120t + 100)$ but its wrong because the answer gives me 1.9, and it should be less than 1 so when multiplied by 100 it equals a percentage per year.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to take the log, just differentiate $y(t)$ to get $$y'(t)=12 \frac 32[(t/10)+1]^{1/2}\frac 1{10}$$  Now divide this by $y(t)$ to get the ratio you desire.  A lot of factors cancel.

Comment: oooookay, I see it now, i got 15% per year. Eureka! thank you Ross!